# How to automatically increase the character varying length in database with hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
     @Column(length = 2)
     private String name;
}
```

This creates a `character varying(2)` in db. When I change the lenght to a bigger value, eg 5, the database is not altered.

Is there any chance that hibernate can actually modify the length (at least extending)?

Comment: have you checked the length of it in Database?

Comment: I don't think Hibernate Auto DDL handles ALTER TABLEs well, you're safer doing it manually. Try with hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = update anyway, if not doesn't work, you might look after Liquibase, it can alter your database when you start the application.

Comment: I have auto=update already...

Answer (score 0):

Try hbm2ddl.auto=update, then it should update the table. But be careful with that feature.

Answer (score 0):

**hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto**

this functionality depends on the quality of the metadata provided by the JDBC driver, an area in which many drivers are lacking.

Also Hibernate docs suggest

> The SchemaUpdate tool will update an existing schema with
>   "incremental" changes. The SchemaUpdate depends upon the JDBC metadata
>   API and, as such, will not work with all JDBC drivers.

Seems like the issue of driver support for incremental updates. Also it does not make sense to give support to update the datatype of columns. What will happens to the existing data if the modified column datatype is a scaled down version of earlier datatype.